# Resize photos automatically in a portfolio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website as a portfolio for a graphic designer friend. I want to be able to import pictures of different sizes a bit like on this website https://victorthemes.com/themes/fraxos/home-version-two/

I tried replicating the design using bootstrap but the column system doesn't work in this case.

Upon further inspection, I realized that the position "top" and "left" move automatically depending on window size.

I was wondering if anyone could inform me on how to get to this result, plugin, template, JS or JQuery ... and if someone has an example I would be grateful to see it.

I'm looking for templates - including WordPress templates - but I can't really find what I want.

Comment: You need to include your code for what you've tried so far. However, what you're looking for is a masonry type layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you are showing might as well be made with a *grid* plugin, like the one found here:

http://gridstackjs.com/

However, based on what you said about 'different photo sizes', you *might* be looking for what is called a *masonry layout*. Check the following plugin link that also includes examples:

https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you, yes i probably want something like masonry layout. I'll check the link ;)

Comment: @Pierre Bordas, if you think this is the answer to your question then click on the tick on the left side of the answer to mark it so that you give credit and let other users know that you found the answer to your issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use UIkit for your framework -- it comes built in with a masonry style grid.

https://getuikit.com/docs/grid

Comment: Thank you for your help